# Need to set and get the value of the clicked link

Tags: codeigniter

The code below is the display of search result of my project. The code below will display more than 1 row of result which I will put a link to every `$value['name']`  to proceed to the next page. I need to get which link is clicked and I need to get the `$value['name']` which corresponds to the link clicked. Can someone help me please.

```
        <div id="searchBox"> 






      <?php

   foreach( $row as $value ) // VALUE IS A ROW
   {?>


    <?php echo " Name: ";
    ?>  <a href='<?php echo base_url()."main/moreinfo" ?>'><?php echo $value['name']; ? ></a>

    <?php

     echo '<p>';
     echo " Type: ";
     echo $value['type'];
     echo '<p>';
       echo "________________________________________________________________________";
    echo '<p>';


     }



       ?>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You achieve this adding an id `$value['id']` to your `<a href>`. Then you are able to query more info in your controller, after the link was clicked:

```
<div id="searchBox"> 
    <?php
        foreach( $row as $value ) {
            $url=base_url( "main/moreinfo/".$value['id'] );
            echo 'Name: ';
            echo '<a href='.$url.'>'.$value['name'].'</a>';
            echo '<p>';
            echo ' Type: ';
            echo $value['type'];
            echo '<p>';
            echo '____________________________________________________________';
            echo '<p>';    
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I use the $url in my model?
$this->input->post('$url'); is not working

Comment: the code you provided indicates that you have a controller 'main' with a function 'moreinfo()'. You get the id using '$this->uri->segment(n)' to use it in your function. More info about CI Uri Class here:http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html